# How can I see the compiled coffeescript in Rails 3.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine, and wondered if there was any way to see the Javascript that Coffeescript compiles to *while I am developing* (prior to the page load).

It's not essential, I was more curious than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click a file in the editor or project view, select "Preview Compiled CoffeeScript File..."

Comment: Ok, that's pretty awesome, I'm liking RubyMine even more now.